# @Scheduled method not running in a specific class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have some scheduled methods in my spring boot project in different classes.Lets say these classes are ClassA,ClassB and ClassC. All of those classes are in the same package. I have @EnableScheduling over my main method in the MainApplication class.

All of these methods read their cron expression from the application.properties file. I have also checked for improper imports of the @Scheduled annotation. All the files have the same import but no matter what I can't get to run any scheduled method from ClassA.

```
@Service
public class ClassB{
   
   @Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 15 * ?")
   public void attendanceCalculator(){
       //this one runs fine
   }

}
```

Another one is like this

```
@Service
public class ClassB{
   
   @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 ? * * ")
   public void dailyAttSummaryGenerator(){
       //this one runs fine too
   }

}
```

But these don't run no matter what I do

```
@Service
public class ClassA{
   
   @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 ? * * ")
   public void testOne(){
       //this one doesn't run
   }
   
   @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
   public void testTwo(){
       //this one doesn't run either
   }

}
```

But strangely enough this works

```
@Service
public class ClassB{
   @Autowired
   public ClassA classA;
     
   @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 ? * * ")
   public void testOne(){
       classA.testOne(); // This runs
   }

   @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
   public void testTwo(){
      classA.testTwo(); // This runs too
   }


}
```

This also works if I autowire classA inside ClassC.

Could someone please explain to me why this might be happening or what I might be doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to debug

Comment: Are `ClassA` and `ClassB` in different packages? Maybe there's a scanning misconfiguration.

Comment: ClassA,ClassB and ClassC are all in the same package. This is what is making me very confused  @sp00m

Comment: Is it possible that you're limited to the number of threads in the scheduled task pool? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#spring.task.scheduling.pool.size

Comment: @ThomasKåsene: Tested with pool-size = 1 as shown in answer below, but still no luck. BR

Comment: There is too little information in your question to answer this. I doubt that you have shown the whole picture and that you have obfuscated too much. I suspect some Spring framework interfaces are in play or one class being used in a post processor. However as stated there is too little information here to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Solution for OP in this case was to clear the .m2 folder.

---

I was able to recreate the behaviour of non-running schedules for `ClassA` on my computer by enabling `lazy-initialization`

```
spring:
  main:
    lazy-initialization: true
```

Unfortunately, same happened to `ClassB` until I autowired `ClassB` into a component that gets initialized during startup.

Annotating ClassA with `@Lazy(false)` brought things back to before turning on lazy-init.

@ThomasKåsene suggested in a comment above that problem may be related to number of threads in scheduled thread pool. Hence, I tested a config with pool-size = 1, but was not able to recreate the behaviour with this config.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfigCron implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    }
}
```

After testing different angles, I tend to suspect that it will be difficult (impossible?) to recreate the whole scenario in an environment different from OP's environment.

Comment: It's so weird, I just create a class like ClassB and everything was fine on my computer, both scheduled methods works fine!

Comment: Do you mean both Classes? inside each other?

Comment: aha, yes it's fine too

Comment: I tried with pool size to 1 too. Does not work for me either. Whats really weird is scheduled methods are running for new classes too. Just not in ClassA. Class A is originally named DailyScheduledEarnedLeaveCalculatorService. I am catching at straw here.... could the name of the class be causing problems?

Comment: @RisalatZaman: I don't think so unless there are remnants of this class in your build. What about creating a ClassD that is similar to ClassA and retest?

Comment: Okay I could not run the scheduled methods either when I copied the contents of classA into a new class classD. Only difference between the other classes and this one is I have a tests written for a function in classA, could this attribute to the problem somehow?

Comment: @RisalatZaman: No, a test class should not cause problems. Let's try to wipe your .m2-folder just to make sure you don't have any leftovers.

Comment: Ok I am going to wipe my .m2 folder then remove methods 1 by 1 from class A and will get back to you. Thanks for all the help @Roar.S

Comment: Ok after clearing .m2 folder copying the code from classA to a new class works. I am going to let this go and accept your answer. @Roar S.

Comment: @RisalatZaman: Great to hear that. And thanks for accepting my answer. BR